# Android application : how to manage handwriting input?

Tags: java, android

I just want to know if there is some existing libraries to manage handwriting input/recognition?
I want to develop an application in which the user could write his text with a srylus, and not with a keyboard. I did research on Google and didn't find anything efficient for that.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Phatware](http://www.phatware.com/) has an [SDK for their Writepad product](http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=product/details/developer/writepadsdk), but only on iOS.

I don't see any public libraries available, but here's an SO post about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768664/recommendations-for-handwriting-recognition-libraries-packages-in-java

Comment: Finally, I use some classes who are still in development. I have included in my project a class called FingerPaint.java, GraphicsActivity.java, PictureLayout.java and ColorPickerDialog.java (optional), not really useful for me right now. You could find these different classes in the [Android documentation - API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I use some classes who are still in development. I have included in my project a class called FingerPaint.java, GraphicsActivity.java, PictureLayout.java and ColorPickerDialog.java (optional), not really useful for me right now. You could find these different classes here: [FingerPaint](http://gitorious.org/freebroid/development/source/62e92d7a2a3fd2798901ec2e7c452ff0e4067163%3asamples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java)

I worked pretty well for me, here is an app using it: [Electronic calendar on Github](https://github.com/jrm2k6/ElectronicCalendar)

Answer (score 0):

MyScript algorithm for recognizing handwritting input(such as normal input, math, geometry, music). Here's the link http://myscript.com/